# Write json object into CSV file using php

Tags: php, json, csv

I'm trying to write the json object into a CSV file, but it's not working the file is empty.

any advice?

below my PHP code

```
//json to csv
$jsondata = '{"regNo":"92-212-98","tradName":"FEVADOL EXTRA TAB.","genericName":"PARACETAMOL, CAFFEINE","price":"5.300","strngth":"500, 65 mg","exD":"21/07","PRODREGSTATUS":"PRODNOTFOUND","authstatus":"1","marketingstatus":"1","productstatus":null}';
$json = json_decode($jsondata);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

// if($fp == false){
// echo 'false open';
// }else{
//  echo 'true open';
// }

foreach ($json as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: `$jsondata` is a string here. You might need to run it through `json_decode()` first to get an array or object you can iterate over.

Comment: Additionally, you might want to check if `$fp` is equal to `false`. If so, that means PHP was unable to open the file for writing. That should trigger a warning, but those may be hidden depending on your settings.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I update my question, but it's open the file successfully.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I update my question, but with no luck even after adding json_decode(), the file is empty.

Comment: You need to enable [error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) in your local development box so you can see "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: fputcsv(): Argument #2 ($fields) must be of type array, string given". I get ignored almost every time I give this piece of advice but that's the only sensible way to develop.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of `fputcsv` function must be an array that shows cells of a row. More information: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

The problem will solve if you change the `for` part of code as following:

```
foreach ($json as $index => $field) {
    fputcsv($fp, [$index, $field]);
}
```